# Pandoc re-run latex filter on element after latex+raw_tex and lua filter

Tags: lua, latex, pandoc

I've been writing a custom LaTeX reader Lua filter to convert a bunch of LaTeX source into Pandoc Markdown, which will be my new source for several documents.

I run the usual filter like the following.

```sh
pandoc file.tex \ 
  -f latex+raw_tex \
  -t markdown \
  -o file.md \
  --lua-filter myfilter.lua
```

This works great. I've been able to convert several custom LaTeX environments into `Div`s and the like.

However, when I have standard LaTeX nested **inside** the custom environment, the filter output leaves that as-is, unconverted. For example.

```latex
\begin{custom_environment}
\begin{itemize}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{itemize}
\end{custom_environment}
```

The custom environment is handled just fine by my filter, but the internal `itemize` or `tabular` or similar are, left unprocessed, as you would expect.

Is there some way to process the **contents** of the custom environment using the standard `latex` extension (i.e. filter)? I assume it would be a call from the Lua filter.

An idea I have for doing this that I'm trying to avoid is writing the contents to a temporary file and running another `pandoc` on that. It seems like such a ubiquitous situation that I'm hoping there's a better way. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying `walk_block` and `walk_inline` now and it looks promising ... will report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found was `pandoc.read`:
https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#helper-functions

I used it as follows.

```lua
internal_div = pandoc.Div(
    pandoc.read(
        contents_of_custom_environment,
        'latex'
    ).blocks,
    'div_label'
)
```

Now `internal_div` contains the `latex`-processed contents of the custom environment. Note that `contents_of_custom_environment` is just a string.

I tried using `walk_block` and `walk_inline`, but couldn't get them to work quite like this. I would welcome an answer that did so.

Comment: Fwiw, I could get `walk_block` and `walk_inline` to apply sub-filters I defined, but I couldn't figure out how to make them apply the OG `latex+raw_tex` extension/filter. Using `read` is fine, but it would be nice to have a way to do something similar with `walk_x`.